# Titanium Studio Alloy visual error in scrollview and view

Tags: iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

Am new to Titanium studio Alloy i have two questions,

1, I created 2 view tag within window on xml file. while am executing last view only visible among the both view my code is

```
<Window class="container>
<View class="View1">
  #content of view1
</View>
<View class="View2">
  #content of view2
</View>
</Window>
```

In this code only last view(view2) is visible i want to visible both view.

2.In my ScrollView tag i have some content to visible. but scrollview content was osculating everywhere in the screen.

i want to be fix with in the screen.

can anyone help me 
advance thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the layout property on your window they are being drawn on top of each other